# Copy/Move File from local folder to SharePoint through Excel macro (vba) programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a requirement to copy the file from local system to SharePoint under specific documents folder (i.e. https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/MyProjects/Shared Documents) using excel macro.

I have an access to upload/add the files manually in the SharePoint portal. I tried to use the sample code like below in macro

```
Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As WshNetwork
Dim FS As Object

SharepointAddress = "\\mycompany.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\myProjects\Shared Documents\"
LocalAddress = "D:\test.xlsx"
Set objNet = New WshNetwork
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objNet.MapNetworkDrive "A:", "\\mycompany.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\myProjects\Shared Documents\"    

FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
```

I used the above sample code by mapping the SharePoint to local network drive. But, It is not working for me.

Can any one help me to resolve this if you have done something similar to this?